# Issue with jQuery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-selectors

```
    <div class="full_width_last">

        <div class="sub_div1" style="display:none">
            <h2>Join</h2>
            <p>Click here to sign up.</p>
            <p>ID: 48</p>
        </div>

        <h4>Boston</h4>
        <p>ioiuy</p>
        <a href="#" class="join_button">Join</a>

    </div>

    jQuery('.join_button').bind('click', function(){



        console.log(jQuery(this));
        console.log(jQuery(this).parent());
        console.log(jQuery('.sub_div1', jQuery(this).parent()));
        return false;
    }
```

I'm having trouble with the jQuery selector: `jQuery('.sub_div1', jQuery(this).parent())`

For some reason the library isn't finding the div I'm searching for.

Both:

```
console.log(jQuery(this));
            console.log(jQuery(this).parent());
```

work as expected. Anyone know why I can't get a reference to .sub_div1?

**EDIT 1**:
Tried caching the parent but this did not work:

```
console.log(jQuery(this));
        //console.log(jQuery(this).parent());
        var p = jQuery(this).parent();
        console.log(jQuery('.sub_div1', p));
```

**EDIT 2**
`jQuery(this).parent().children(".sub_div1")` also did not work

This code produced this result:

```
console.log(jQuery(this));
console.log(jQuery(this).parent());
console.log(jQuery(this).parent().children(".sub_div1"));

Query(a.join_button #✉)
jQuery(div.full_width_last)
jQuery()
```

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: also try caching the parent and see if that works: `var p = jQuery(this).parent(); jQuery('.sub_div1', p);`  BTW, you know that jQuery is most inefficient when looking up a class, it's better to list element.className (eg `div.sub_div1`) than just the class by itself.  That way jQuery can take advantage of the native functions.

Comment: @BoltClock, 1.6.2 - being served from https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js

Comment: @Casey Flynn: What if you use `.find()` or `.siblings()` instead? Do they work?

Comment: @vol7ron, i tried your idea but unfortunately it did not work.

Comment: @BoltClock, I tried .find() and .children() without luck. I can try .siblings()

Comment: works for me:http://jsfiddle.net/vol7ron/L32zR/   you were missing the closing `);` to the bind

Comment: @vol7ron: I'm fairly positive that syntax errors would completely prevent the code from running rather than allowing the first two `console.log`s to execute. So that's not the real issue.

Comment: it seems to be working as expected with jQuery 1.6.2 in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/william/rSVFZ/ There is perhaps some other problem in your code, e.g. have you included jQuery multiple times? Can you show us how you included your scripts?

Comment: Easier to visualise: http://jsfiddle.net/william/rSVFZ/1/

Comment: I could show you the website but it's currently private and only a white list of ips can access it. If you're comfortable with sharing your ip address I can add it to the white list and show you the site.

Comment: Your code [work fine](http://jsfiddle.net/alfonsoR/q47Gm/).

Comment: What have you excluded from the code in the question?

Comment: I think it would be the best for us to help you if you replicate it in a public domain, e.g. jsfiddle.

Comment: I think I figured out what the problem was. I had a div I had forgotten to remove that contained an ID property with a value equal to the class property of the div I specified. Apparently the caused all of the problems.

Comment: IDs and Classes shouldn't conflict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(function($){    
    $('.join_button').bind('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log($(this).siblings('.sub_div1'));
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

try using this,  `jQuery(this).parent().children(".sub_div1")`

Answer (score 0):

Try `jQuery(this).parent().eq(".sub_div1")`

Answer (score 0):

Curious why you're getting the parent and then the children, why not just `jQuery(this).siblings('.sub_div1')`

However, based on your comment, you're not supplying the full detail (or at least enough) of your HTML.